# How many bits shift is a TEA encryption?

Tags: tea

```
void encrypt (unsigned long* v, unsigned long* k) {

unsigned long v0=v[0], v1=v[1], sum=0, i;           /* set up */
unsigned long delta=0x9e3779b9;                     /* a key schedule constant */
unsigned long k0=k[0], k1=k[1], k2=k[2], k3=k[3];   /* cache key */
for (i=0; i < 32; i++) {                       /* basic cycle start */
    sum += delta;
    v0 += ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1);
    v1 += ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3);
}                                              /* end cycle */
v[0]=v0; v[1]=v1;

}
```

I saw this code on the wiki of TEA encryption and was wondering is this considered a 4-bit or 5-bit algorithm since there was a shift of 4 bits to the left but a shift of 5 bit to the right.

I am confused on the algorithm of this encryption and would appreciate it if somebody can clarify it for me.

Thank you

Comment: I've never heard of a classification of algorithms by shift amount.

Comment: ARE you sure is from wiki? OR FROM lecture slides?bro? I know who you are, have fun guessing who I am.

Comment: Haha, this man-child is funny. Oh well. Doesn't take long to figure out a childish kid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEA is neither considered a 4-bit nor 5-bit algorithm (these are not categorized by their shift count). TEA:

- Is a 64-bit block cipher, meaning `encrypt` modifies 64 bits: the block is `v[0]` `v[1]` and the code shown (non-portably) assumes `unsigned long` is 32-bit.
- Has a 128-bit key `k[0]` `k[1]` `k[2]` `k[3]` ; notice that each key has 3 other equivalent ones (obtained by complementing the high-order bits of even or/and odd numbered words), thus key is effectively 126-bit.
- Performs 32 double rounds, with in each double round (focusing on shifts because that's asked) two left shifts by 4 bits and two right shifts by 5 bits (on a 32-bit quantity). That's 128 shifts on a machine with a 32-bit [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter), and 5760 shifts with a 32-bit [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) without barrel shifter.

Addition: the only two common reasons to count the shifts in an algorithm are:

- Determine how much computational effort is spent on that, to predict how the CPU influences the performance. Continuing on that track: on 8-bit CPU, 32-bit shifts are quite expensive, and naive code with likely have 23040 shift instructions executed per bloc encrypted, with shifting representing I guess like 3/4 of the effort. In assembly language at least, it is possible to do significantly better by realizing that most bits of `v1>>5` can be obtained as `((v1<<4)>>8)>>1`, with the shift by 8 efficient on an 8-bit CPU. Also, many 8-bit CPUs have an instruction that swaps the halves of an octet, and might be put to use for the shift by 4.
- Determining is there's enough [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion). In TEA, it is used shift rather than rotations (largely because there is no built-in rotation in the C language, and building one would have made at least the source code more complex), and therefore diffusion across bits of the 32 ranks in 32-bit words is mostly by shifting (exclusively so for right diffusion, and with carry propagation contributing slightly to left diffusion). Full diffusion requires about 8 rounds, and that is significantly slower than say in DES, which diffuses I'd say more than twice faster. That's one of several reasons TEA must have a lot of rounds (64 rounds versus 16 in DES).